# Generic CRUD Http Functions in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, dio

I would like to make the basic http crud functions generic in my flutter app. The whole thing should look like this:

```
class HttpGenericClient {
  static Future<T> create<T>(String path, {required T data}) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> parsedData = data.toJson();
    final Response<Map<String, dynamic>> response = await httpClient.post<Map<String, dynamic>>(path, data: data);

    final T preparedData = T.fromJson(response.data);

    return preparedData;
  }
}

HttpGenericClient.create<User>('/users', user);
```

I'm using the json_serializable package that created the fromJson & toJson methods. The problem is that I can't call them on the T-type. Does anyone have any idea how to best solve this?

Furthermore, I don't think it's nice if you have to give the path with every call. Isn't there a nicer solution here that I can somehow define the path in the model and access it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to do that, for example you can add HTTP calls as methods to your model class. In the following example there is a simple `MyObject` class, and a `create` method that you can call to create in the database.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class MyObject {
  int? id;
  String name;
  MyObject({required this.name}) : super();

  MyObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        name = json['name'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
      };

  Future<bool> create() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.https(<YOUR_API_BASE_URL>, '/myobject'),
          headers: {'authorization': <YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN>}, // if needed
          body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
            'data': this.toJson(),
          }));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // let's say you get back id of the created record
        // in "data" tag
        id = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"];
        return true;
      } else {
        // handler errors
        return false;
      }
    } on SocketException {
      // do something when there is a network error
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can create a new instance and save it like this:

```
  final myObject = MyObject(name: 'SomeNewName');
  if (!await myObject.create()) {
    // handle errors
  }
```

If it is a success, you will have your new data in `myObject`, including `id` returned from the `POST` call. This is just an example, adjust it to your logic.